# Seems not a Kinesis client library application for spark plus kinesis integration

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-kinesis

I am going through the code
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/extras/kinesis-asl/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaKinesisWordCountASL.java

it shows how kinesis can emit stream data to SparkContext and then spark can process further.

in the given example code i am trying to understand how this code is KCL application
if i see 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-java.html
it says 
You must complete the following tasks when implementing an Amazon Kinesis application in Java:

Tasks

Implement the IRecordProcessor Methods
Implement a Class Factory for the IRecordProcessor Interface
Modify the Configuration Properties

but the spark example code 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/extras/kinesis-asl/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaKinesisWordCountASL.java has no reference for IRecordProcessor  and worker etc.

Note: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-kinesis-integration.html under deploying section it says
A single Kinesis input DStream can read from multiple shards of a Kinesis stream by creating multiple KinesisRecordProcessor threads.
But there is no implementation of KinesisRecordProcessor  is it missing . Or i am missing something obvious to understand

Could somebody please explain me how this is KCL application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kinesis streaming implementation takes care of those interactions and abstracts away from the app. See https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/extras/kinesis-asl/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kinesis

Comment: could you please add java example . sorry i am not good with scala to understand this abstraction layer

Comment: Scala has full interoperability with Java so the code can be mixed. The JavaKinesisWordCountASL calls the KinesisUtils from the Spark Kinesis streaming assembly. The KinesisUtils is in Scala and is where you will find the references to the KCL.